# Proving that restriction of linear operator to invariant set has same eigenvectors as linear operator

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, spectral-theory, symmetric-matrices

I am hung-up on one part of the proof of the spectral theorem for real matrices. The proof by induction makes perfect sense, but when I try to write it using only matrices I'm struggling to show that the eigenvalues of $B$ are the same as $A$.

## Quick proof of spectral theorem of real, linear operators on $\mathbb{R}^n$ by induction

---

Here's a quick rundown of the proof by induction that I am referring to:

**Base case.**
Let let $V$ be an inner product space of $\dim V = 1$ and $T$ a self-adjoint linear operator $T: V \to V$. Then $T$ has a real eigenvalue $\lambda$ and corresponding real eigenvector $\mathbf{v}\in \mathbb{R}$. Now, $\frac{\mathbf{v}}{\| \mathbf{v} \|}$ spans $\mathbb{R}$.

**Inductive step.**
Now let $\dim V = n+1$. $T$ again has a real eigenvalue $\lambda$ and corresponding real eigenvector $\mathbf{v}$. Let $U = \text{span} \{ \mathbf{v} \}$, so $U^\perp = \{ \mathbf{u} \in V \; | \; \langle \mathbf{u}, \mathbf{v} \rangle = 0\}$.

Note that $\dim U^\perp = n$ and that $U^\perp$ is invariant under $T$ as
$$
\langle T(\mathbf{u}), \mathbf{v} \rangle = \langle \mathbf{u}, T(\mathbf{v}) \rangle = \langle \mathbf{u}, \lambda \mathbf{v} \rangle = \lambda \langle \mathbf{u}, \mathbf{v} \rangle = 0 \; , \; \forall \mathbf{u} \in U^\perp
$$
Define $E : U^\perp \to U^\perp$, where $E = \left. T \right|_{U^\perp}$, then $E$ is self-adjoint
$$
\langle E(\mathbf{u}_1) , \mathbf{u}_2 \rangle = \langle T(\mathbf{u}_1) , \mathbf{u}_2 \rangle = \langle \mathbf{u}_1 , T(\mathbf{u}_2) \rangle = \langle \mathbf{u}_1 , E(\mathbf{u}_2) \rangle
$$
Thus, by the inductive hypothesis, $E$ has $n$ orthonormal eigenvectors that span $U^\perp$ and because
$$
E(\mathbf{x}) = \omega \mathbf{x} = T(\mathbf{x})
$$
where $(\omega, \mathbf{x})$ is an eigenpair of $E$, then all eigenvectors of $E$ are also eigenvectors of $T$, so $T$ admits a spectral decomposition $\, \blacksquare$

Now I'd like to show this by using matrices.

## Attempt to prove with matrix math

---

**Base case.** Let $A = A^\top \in \mathbb{R}^{1 \times 1}$. $A$ has a real eigenvalue $\lambda \in \mathbb{R}$ and eigenvector $\mathbf{v} \in \mathbb{R}$, and $\frac{\mathbf{v}}{\| \mathbf{v} \|}$ spans $\mathbb{R} $

**Inductive step.** Let $A = A^\top \in \mathbb{R}^{(n + 1) \times (n + 1)}$. Again
$$
\exists \lambda \in \mathbb{R} \exists \mathbf{v} \in \mathbb{R}^{n+1} \; | \; A \mathbf{v} = \lambda \mathbf{v}
$$
because the fundamental theorem of algebra tells us that the characteristic polynomial of $A$ will have $n+1$ roots counted with algebraic multiplicity, and $A$'s symmetry tells us that the root(s) are real, and let $(\lambda, \mathbf{v})$ be an eigenpair of $A$.  Let $U = \text{span}\{ \mathbf{v} \}$ and thus
$$
U^\perp = \{ \mathbf{u} \in \mathbb{R}^{n+1} \; | \; \langle \mathbf{u}, \mathbf{v} \rangle = \mathbf{u} \cdot \mathbf{v} = \mathbf{u}^\top \mathbf{v} = 0 \}
$$
Since $A$ is symmetric, $U^\perp$ is invariant under $A$:
$$
A \mathbf{u} \cdot \mathbf{v} = (A \mathbf{u})^\top \mathbf{v} = \mathbf{u}^\top A^\top \mathbf{v} = \mathbf{u}^\top A \mathbf{v} = \mathbf{u}^\top (\lambda \mathbf{v}) = \lambda \mathbf{u}^\top \mathbf{v} = \lambda (\mathbf{u} \cdot \mathbf{v}) = 0
$$
thus $A \mathbf{u} \in U^\perp$, for all $\mathbf{u} \in U^\perp$.

Now let $\{\mathbf{y}_1 , \dots, \mathbf{y}_n \}$ be a basis of $U^\perp$, and let $Y = \left[\begin{smallmatrix}\mathbf{y}_1 & \dots & \mathbf{y}_n \end{smallmatrix}\right] \in \mathbb{R}^{(n+1) \times n}$. Note that $\dim U^\perp = n$ since $\dim U = 1$. Let $B$ be the transformation described by $A$ in the basis $\{\mathbf{y}_i \}$, defined as
$$
B_{ij} = \langle A\mathbf{y}_j, \mathbf{y}_i \rangle = \sum_{k=1}^n AY_{jk}Y_{ki} = Y^\top A Y
$$
that is, the $ij$-th entry of $B \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$ is the $i$-th coordinate (w.r.t. $\{ \mathbf{y}_i \}$) of the transformed $\mathbf{y}_j$. The punchline is
$$
B^\top = (Y^\top AY)^\top = Y^\top A^\top Y
$$
so $B$ is symmetric because $A$ is symmetric.

Thus, by the inductive hypothesis, $B$ admits an orthonormal eigenbasis of $\mathbb{R}^n$.

## The point where I'm stuck

---

At this point, the proofs I've read usually say something along the lines of:

> Since $B$ is the transformation $A$ in the basis $\{ \mathbf{y}_i \}$, then all eigenvectors of $B$ are also eigenvectors of $A$, and further, these eigenvectors are orthogonal to $\mathbf{v}$, thus $A$ admits an orthonormal eigenbasis.

Which makes perfect sense; however, since we know this is true we should be able to show the fact that the eigenvectors of $B$ are also eigenvectors of $A$ using just matrices (i.e. the math should work out).

### Attempt

My attempt was to let $(\mu, \mathbf{x})$ be an eigenpair of $B$. Then
$$
B \mathbf{x} = \mu \mathbf{x} = Y^\top A Y \mathbf{x} 
$$
So $Y \mathbf{x}$ is $\mathbf{x}$ in the standard basis of $\mathbb{R}^{n+1}$, so I'll nickname it $\mathbf{m}$, so this gives us
$$
Y B \mathbf{x} = Y \mu \mathbf{x} = \mu \mathbf{m} = Y Y^\top A \mathbf{m}
$$
at this point, I wanted to say something about $Y Y^\top$, as in if $Y$ is an orthogonal matrix then we have the desired result, but it isn't since $Y \in \mathbb{R}^{(n+1) \times n}$, so it can't be.

## My question/TLDR

---

My question written out explicitly is:

If $A \in \mathbb{R}^{(n+1)\times (n+1)}$ and $B \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n} $ are both symmetric, and $B = Y^\top A Y$, prove that all eigenvectors of $B$ are also eigenvectors of $A$, i.e. show that if
$$
B \mathbf{x} = \mu \mathbf{x}
$$
and $Y \mathbf{x} = \mathbf{m}$, then
$$
A \mathbf{m} = \mu \mathbf{m}
$$

Comment: What does it mean for a non-square matrix to be symmetric?

Answer (score 1):

The piece of data you are missing is that, because $y_1,\ldots,y_n$ is an orthonormal basis for $U^\perp$, then $YY^\top$ is the orthogonal projection onto $U^\perp$. Thus from $B=Y^\top AY$ and $Bx=\mu x$ you get, since $Yx\in U^\perp$,
$$
A(Yx)=YY^\top AYx=YBx=Y(\mu x)=\mu(Yx).
$$

Answer (score 0):

I think I've got it:

Another requirement/something that is worth emphasizing: $\{ \mathbf{y}_i \}$ is an orthonormal basis of $U^\perp$, so
\begin{gather}
Y^\top Y = I
\end{gather}
since
\begin{gather}
(Y^\top Y)_{ij} = \sum_k Y^\top_{ik} Y_{kj} = \sum_k Y_{ki} Y_{kj} = \langle \mathbf{y}_i, \mathbf{y}_j \rangle = \mathbf{y}_i \cdot \mathbf{y}_j = \delta_{ij}
\end{gather}
Then, since $Y \mathbf{x} = \mathbf{m}$
\begin{gather}
Y^\top \mathbf{m} = \mathbf{x}
\end{gather}
then
\begin{gather}
B \mathbf{x} = \mu \mathbf{x} \xrightarrow[B = Y^\top A Y]{} Y^\top A Y \mathbf{x} = \mu \mathbf{x}
\end{gather}
Now replace $\mathbf{x}$ with $Y^\top \mathbf{m}$, and replace $Y \mathbf{x}$ with $\mathbf{m}$
\begin{gather}
Y^\top A \mathbf{m} = \mu Y^\top \mathbf{m} \to Y^\top (A\mathbf{m} - \mu \mathbf{m}) = \mathbf{0}
\end{gather}
Which means that $A\mathbf{m} - \mu \mathbf{m}$ is either orthogonal to $U^\perp$, or $A\mathbf{m} - \mu \mathbf{m}= \mathbf{0}$. Since $\text{im } Y = U^\perp$, $\mathbf{m} \in U^\top$, and since $U^\top$ is invariant under $A$, then $A\mathbf{m} - \mu \mathbf{m} \in U^\perp$ and thus
$$
A\mathbf{m} - \mu \mathbf{m} = \mathbf{0} \quad \blacksquare
$$

So we can take $B$'s orthonormal eigenbasis, $\{ \mathbf{x}_i \}$, and let
$$
X = \begin{bmatrix} \mathbf{x}_1 & \dots & \mathbf{x}_n \end{bmatrix}
$$
then
$$
YX = \begin{bmatrix} Y\mathbf{x}_1 & \dots & Y\mathbf{x}_n \end{bmatrix}
$$
are all eigenvectors of $A$, and the eigenvectors are all orthogonal since the eigenvalues are real. So if we take all of those eigenvectors of $A$ with the original eigenvector $\mathbf{v}$ (and normalize), we get the orthonormal eigenbasis of $A$:
$$
\{ Y\mathbf{x}_i \} \cup \{ \mathbf{v} \}
$$